# Why doesn't openapi-generator-cli annotate ASP.NET Core controller with [Produces("application/json")]?

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, swashbuckle, openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator-cli to generate server code for an ASP.NET Core application from an OpenAPI 3.0.0 specification. In my OpenAPI document, the response media type for the API is explicitly set to application/json.

Here's a simplified snippet from my OpenAPI YAML file:

```
  paths:
  /example:
    get:
      summary: "Get example data"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successful response"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Example"
```

After generating the code using the aspnetcore option (-g aspnetcore), I noticed that the generated controllers are not annotated with [Produces("application/json")].

As a consequence, when I use Swashbuckle to create a Swagger page, the drop-down for media types shows multiple options and defaults to text/plain, despite application/json being the only defined media type in my OpenAPI document.

Is this a missing feature in openapi-generator-cli or is there something I might be overlooking in my configuration that is causing this issue?